# inner join two table of 2 column to the same ID

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

I'm starting to learn "sqllite3" and I faced a problem which I could not figure out.

I have these tables

[image: Schema]

and I want to select
the following date of each passenger :
Name,sex,age, ticket,Fare, Origin port and Destination port.
But in the Origin and destination ports I want to show the Port name not the number.
I manged to show all the data except the ports, I know i need to use Alias, but don't know how.
can anyone help?

```
select Passengers.Passengerid as "PassengerId", Classes.Class_Name as 
"Passenger_Class", Passengers.Name, Passengers.Sex,Passengers.Age, 
Travels.Ticket,Travels.Fare, Ports.Port_ID as "Embarked",Ports.Port_ID as 
"Destination" from Passengers
inner join Travels on Passengers.Passengerid = Travels.Passengerid
inner join Travel_Options on Travels.Travel_ID = Travel_Options.Travel_ID
inner join Ports on Travel_Options.Origin_Port_ID =  Ports.Port_ID
inner join Ports on Travel_Options.Destination_ID =  Ports.Port_ID
inner join Classes on Travel_Options.Class_ID = Classes.Class_ID;
```

Comment: give different alias to the tables with same name like `inner join Ports p1` and `inner join Ports p2` and use `p2` as if it is the table name for the columns `p1.Ports.Port_ID` `p2.whatevercolumn`

Comment: `Travel_Options.Origin_Port_ID =  Ports.Port_ID` becames `Travel_Options.Origin_Port_ID =  p1.Port_ID` ...

Answer (score 2):

You need separate aliases for the tables.  In fact, I would recommend table aliases for *all* your tables:

```
select p.Passengerid, c.Class_Name as Passenger_Class,
       p.Name, p.Sex, p.Age, 
       t.Ticket, t.Fare, po.port_name as Embarked, pd.port_name as  Destination
from Passengers p inner join
     Travels t
     on p.Passengerid = t.Passengerid inner join
     Travel_Options o
     on t.Travel_ID = o.Travel_ID inner join
     Ports po
     on o.Origin_Port_ID = po.Port_ID inner join
     Ports pd
     on o.Destination_ID = pd.Port_ID inner join
     Classes c
     on o.Class_ID = c.Class_ID;
```